# Ionic build android Error (processArmv7DebugResources)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I have install crosswalk with ionic. However, when I try run "ionic build android" I'm getting the following error:

`:processArmv7DebugResourcesE:\Trabalhos\Aplicativos\Mars Curiosity\structure\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\armv7\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:26:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').`

It seems that drawable resources is not present.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: error is pretty clear.. there is no drawable in the application with the labeled icon

Comment: Thanks @JoxTraex,  I've created a new clear project and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I realy don't found out what caused this. I have created a new blanck project e replace all files withing the www folder, and all worked fine.